# Computing a finite sum containing a floor.

Tags: sequences-and-series

> I'm trying to find the value of the finite sum,
> $$\sum_{k=0}^{72}\lfloor1000\cos\left(5k^{\circ}\right)\rfloor$$

All I can deduce is that $\cos\left(5k^{\circ}\right)$ repeats after every $72^{\circ}$ which should makes the bounds a little better to work with. I also noticed that $\lfloor1000\cos\left(5k^{\circ}\right)\rfloor\in [1000,-1000]$, but I don't know if that would help. Considering the bound is $72$, I'd assume it could be generalized for;
$$\sum_{k=72m}^{72n}\lfloor1000\cos\left(5k^{\circ}\right)\rfloor,m\leq n$$
I first thought of defining the function $\cos\left(5k^{\circ}\right)$ as a piecewise, but that does not help, as there would be $72$ cases for that. I doubt that the property
$$\lfloor{x}\rfloor+\lfloor{-x}\rfloor=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x\in\mathbb{Z}\\-1&\text{if }x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Z}\end{cases}$$
would be used.

Comment: Isn't the sum = $0$? $1000 + (-1000)$, $999 + (-999)$, and so on. In $72$ "steps", it would've completed $1$ full cycle, from *zero* back to *zero*, through, of course, *hero*.

Comment: Well no, the floors mess things up because for non-integers, $\lfloor{x}\rfloor+\lfloor{-x}\rfloor=-1$ and not $0$.

Comment: The property you mention can help if you write $$\sum_{r=0}^{72}\lfloor1000\cos\left(5k^{\circ}\right)\rfloor = \sum_{r=0}^{35} \big(\lfloor1000\cos\left(5k^{\circ}\right)\rfloor + \lfloor1000\cos\left(5(k+36)^{\circ}\right)\rfloor\big) + 1000.$$

Comment: Yet I don't see how that would help. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @wolfqz, aah! $-1.2$ becomes $-2$ and $1.2$ becomes $1$, the two together become $-1$. Sum(integers) = 0, Sum(nonintegers) = -1. The answer should be then $-\infty$ or better simply state it as $\sum = (-1) + (-1) + \dots$

Comment: Well not, Wolfram Alpha numerically confirmed it to be $968$. I'm trying to find a method that isn't brute force.

Comment: While _Wolfram Alpha_ worked, this is a good example of a question one shouldn't ask naïve calculating software, even though it's tempting, because of rounding errors in the degree-to-radian-to-cosine-times-$1000$-to-floor process. Taking Python for example, `from math import cos, floor, radians;print(sum(floor(1000*cos(radians(5*k))) for k in range(73)))` prints `966` instead of `968`. Even less accurately, replacing `floor` with `int` in the second line gets `1001`.

Comment: @wolfqz, you mean $\sum (-1) + (-1) + (-1) ... = 968$. That's messed up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seperating the $\color{green}{\lfloor n\in \mathbb Z\rfloor}$ looking terms i.e $k=0,12,18,24,36,48,54,60,72$.

For, $k=0,12,18,24,36,48,54,60,72$ we get $S_k+S_{k+36}=0$,
$$\lfloor1000\cos\left(5k^{\circ}\right)\rfloor+\lfloor1000\cos\left(5(k+36)^{\circ}\right)\rfloor=\lfloor1000\cos\left(5k^{\circ}\right)\rfloor+\lfloor-1000\cos\left(5k^{\circ}\right)\rfloor=0\\
(\because\lfloor x \rfloor+\lfloor -x \rfloor=0\,; \,x\in \mathbb{Z})$$

Therefore,
$$\sum_{k=12,18,24,36,48,54,60,72}t_k=0$$
Now,

$$\sum_{k=0}^{72}\lfloor1000\cos\left(5k^{\circ}\right)\rfloor{=t_0+(t_{12}+t_{18}+t_{24}+t_{36}+t_{48}+t_{54}+t_{60}+t_{72})+\text{Remaining terms}\\
=1000+\sum_{k=12,18,24,36,48,54,60,72}t_k+\text{Remaining terms}\\
=1000+\text{Remaining terms}}$$

We can observe that $S_k+S_{k+36}=-1$ for the Remaining terms,

$$\lfloor1000\cos\left(5k^{\circ}\right)\rfloor+\lfloor1000\cos\left(5(k+36)^{\circ}\right)\rfloor=\lfloor1000\cos\left(5k^{\circ}\right)\rfloor+\lfloor-1000\cos\left(5k^{\circ}\right)\rfloor=-1\\
(\because\lfloor x \rfloor+\lfloor -x \rfloor=-1\,; \,x\in\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Z})$$

Now, Remaining terms is $64$ terms i.e. $32$ pair of terms.

Hence,
$$\boxed{\sum_{k=0}^{72}\lfloor1000\cos\left(5k^{\circ}\right)\rfloor=1000-32=968}$$

---

**Generalization:**

By observing the pattern,

$1\to72$ is a perfect cycle which repeats again $73\to144$, $145\to216$ and so on.

$$\therefore \sum_{k=1+72n}^{72m} \lfloor1000\cos\left(5k^{\circ}\right)\rfloor=-32(m-n)\quad (\text{Where, }m, n\in \{0,1,2\ldots\} \text{ and }  m > n)$$

Comment: Thank you! From here I'm guessing it's easy to see that,
$$\sum_{k=72m}^{72n}\lfloor1000\cos\left(5k^{\circ}\right)\rfloor=968(n-m),n\geq m$$
or is that incorrect?

Comment: @wolfqz I added the generalization in my answer. Your one is not always correct.